# Joining four tables with MySQL and get values from two of them

Tags: mysql, sql

I looked to similar questions but I did not get to find the right syntax.

I have these tables:

**Quotes**
- quotes_id
- author_id
- quote_ENG

**Authors**
- author_id
- author

**TopicMap**
- topicmap_id
- topics_ENG

**QuotesByTopic**
- quotes_id
- topicmap_id

I need to get 'quote_ENG' from table Quotes and 'author' from table Authors WHERE 'topic_ENG'='age'.

I am able to get the 'quote_ENG' value...:

```
SELECT quote_ENG
FROM Quotes, TopicMap, QuotesByTopic
WHERE TopicMap.topics_ENG='age'
  and QuotesByTopic.topicmap_id = TopicMap.topicmap_id
  and QuotesByTopic.quotes_id = Quotes.quotes_id
```

...but I miss the last passage to get also the 'author' value:

```
SELECT author, quote_ENG
FROM Authors, Quotes, TopicMap, QuotesByTopic
WHERE TopicMap.topics_ENG = 'age'
  and Authors.author_id = Quotes.author_id
  and QuotesByTopic.topicmap_id = TopicMap.topicmap_id
  and QuotesByTopic.quotes_id = Quotes.quotes_id
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Explicit `JOIN` syntax is your friend.

Comment: You are using a JOIN syntax that is over 20 years out of date, [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) highlights a number of reasons to switch to the newer ANSI 92 JOIN syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  q.quote_ENG,
  a.author
FROM QuotesByTopic  AS qt 
INNER JOIN TopicMap AS t ON qt.topicmap_id = t.topicmap_id
INNER JOIN Quotes   AS q ON qt.quotes_id   = q.quotes_id
INNER JOIN Authors  AS a ON a.author_id    = q.author_id
WHERE t.topics_ENG = 'age'
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but unfortunately it seems it doesn't work. It doesn't give me an error because it never stops to load. It's like it's constrained in an infinite loop

Comment: @fabrizio_ff - It is the same way you did but with different syntax, it should work fine, you might need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Does it work fine after that, or doesn't stop never?

Comment: It works but it takes several minutes to get the result. Could it depend on the DB size? The tables have: Authors (17.400 records), Quotes (70.000 records), QuotesByTopic (70.000 records), TopicMap(100 records).

Comment: Maybe it can help to say that I am lunching the query from phpMyAdmin and when it finishes to load the data, and they are visualized in a table, it says that the query needed 0.1080 sec to be performed even though it took several minutes to me to visualize the data. Does it mean something for you? Thanks

Comment: @fabrizio_ff - Ofcourse it depends on the DB sizes, but the more important is the indexes on the tables must setup correctly, I don't know about PHPMyadmin but it seems that you're correct, may be it takes these several minutes in visualising the data, for the indexes, see this page for more info, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Your advice has been very helpful, I setted up correctly the indexes of the tables and now the query is almost immediate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you changed your question as I was typing... I'd still use a distinct incase you want to do something like tma.topics_ENG IN ('age','gender'). As the other person showed I would use explicit joins. A lot easier for everyone, including yourself, to read and understand.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ath.author,
       qts.quote_ENG
FROM quotes qts
INNER JOIN Authors ath
    ON qts.author_id = ath.author_id
INNER JOIN QuotesByTopic qbt
    ON qts.quote_id = qbt.quote_id
INNER JOIN TopicMap tma
    ON qbt.topicmap_id = tma.topicmap_id
WHERE tma.topics_ENG = 'age';
```